# Can't replace character in string var inside a loop when running windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-console

I am making a batch file and I'm trying to print out the path of every file  in a folder but with double backslashes

```
@echo off 


SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


for /r %%i in (%USERPROFILE%\*) do (

    set route=%%i
    set route=%%i:\=\\%%
    echo %%route%% >> output.txt
)
```

The expected values for every data are for example:

Output.txt

```
C:\\Users\\myuser\\...
C:\\Users\\myuser\\...
C:\\Users\\myuser\\...
```

But there are something wrong with my code and I can't achieve my objective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION


for /r "%USERPROFILE%" %%i in (*) do (
    set route=%%i
    set route=!route:\=\\!
    echo !route! 
)
```

See `for /?` from the prompt for `for /r` syntax. Quotes inserted in case of separators in directoryname.

You cannot use a *metavariable* such as `%%i` in a string-manipulation command.

Refer to the changed value of a variable with `!var!` when `delayedexpansion` has been invoked.

Comment: Great! Windows bash is a little tricky, however this solve my need. Thanks.